# Cannot start Cassandra with "bin/cassandra -f"

Tags: cassandra

I have a problem of using Cassandra, I can start it with "bin/cassandra", but cannot start it with "bin/cassandra -f", anyone know the reason?

Here are the detailed info:

```
root@server1:~/cassandra# bin/cassandra -f
 INFO 10:51:31,500 JNA not found. Native methods will be disabled.
 INFO 10:51:31,740 DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
 INFO 10:51:32,043 Deleted /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/LocationInfo-61-Data.db
 INFO 10:51:32,044 Deleted /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/LocationInfo-62-Data.db
 INFO 10:51:32,052 Deleted /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/LocationInfo-63-Data.db
 INFO 10:51:32,053 Deleted /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/LocationInfo-64-Data.db
 INFO 10:51:32,063 Sampling index for /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/LocationInfo-65-Data.db
 INFO 10:51:32,117 Sampling index for /var/lib/cassandra/data/Keyspace1/Standard2-5-Data.db
 INFO 10:51:32,118 Sampling index for /var/lib/cassandra/data/Keyspace1/Standard2-6-Data.db
 INFO 10:51:32,120 Sampling index for /var/lib/cassandra/data/Keyspace1/Standard2-7-Data.db
 INFO 10:51:32,131 Replaying /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-1285869561954.log
 INFO 10:51:32,143 Finished reading /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-1285869561954.log
 INFO 10:51:32,145 Creating new commitlog segment /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-1286301092145.log
 INFO 10:51:32,153 Standard2 has reached its threshold; switching in a fresh Memtable at CommitLogContext(file='/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-1286301092145.log', position=121)
 INFO 10:51:32,155 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-Standard2@1811560891(29 bytes, 1 operations)
 INFO 10:51:32,156 Writing Memtable-Standard2@1811560891(29 bytes, 1 operations)
 INFO 10:51:32,200 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/Keyspace1/Standard2-8-Data.db
 INFO 10:51:32,203 Compacting [org.apache.cassandra.io.SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/Keyspace1/Standard2-5-Data.db'),org.apache.cassandra.io.SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/Keyspace1/Standard2-6-Data.db'),org.apache.cassandra.io.SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/Keyspace1/Standard2-7-Data.db'),org.apache.cassandra.io.SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/Keyspace1/Standard2-8-Data.db')]
 INFO 10:51:32,214 Recovery complete
 INFO 10:51:32,214 Log replay complete
 INFO 10:51:32,230 Saved Token found: 47408016217042861442279446207060121025
 INFO 10:51:32,230 Saved ClusterName found: Test Cluster
 INFO 10:51:32,231 Saved partitioner not found. Using org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner
 INFO 10:51:32,250 LocationInfo has reached its threshold; switching in a fresh Memtable at CommitLogContext(file='/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-1286301092145.log', position=345)
 INFO 10:51:32,250 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-LocationInfo@1120194637(95 bytes, 2 operations)
 INFO 10:51:32,251 Writing Memtable-LocationInfo@1120194637(95 bytes, 2 operations)
 INFO 10:51:32,307 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/LocationInfo-66-Data.db
 INFO 10:51:32,316 Starting up server gossip
 INFO 10:51:32,329 Compacted to /var/lib/cassandra/data/Keyspace1/Standard2-9-Data.db.  1670/1440 bytes for 6 keys.  Time: 125ms.
 INFO 10:51:32,366 Binding thrift service to /172.24.0.80:9160
 INFO 10:51:32,369 Cassandra starting up...
```

Comment: it says Cassandra starting up as the last line in your trace ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cant see any problems? (-f is short for 'foreground')

Comment: Schildmeijer, but after i start it use "-f", why i cannot find the process of Cassandra? I use the command "ps -ef | grep cassandra".

Comment: try search for 'java' instead

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know "-f" is to run on foreground.